# Manage other container with nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, containers

How do I use the nginx in the container and access other container with setup config file?
I am a beginner for docker.
I try to learn how to use nginx manage my applications by docker containers.
I will use the "pgadmin" as an application in container for example.

1. Create & start containers. I try to use the [link] parameter to connect two containers.

   ```
   sudo docker create -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name Nginx nginx
   sudo docker create -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=houzeyu2683@gmail.com -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=20121006 -p 5001:80 --link Nginx:PSQLA --name PSQLA dpage/pgadmin4
   sudo docker start Nginx 
   sudo docker start PSQLA
   ```
2. Go to Nginx bash and install nano edit.

   ```
   sudo docker exec -it Nginx bash
   apt update
   apt install nano
   ```
3. Create and setup the nginx config file in admin.conf.

   ```
   nano etc/nginx/conf.d/admin.conf
   ```

In the admin.conf is following blow.

```
{
  listen 80;
  server_name admin.my-domain-name;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://PSQLA:80;
  }
}
```

I get this error blow.

```
2020/10/17 01:57:16 [emerg] 333#333: host not found in upstream "PSQLA" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/admin.conf:5
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "PSQLA" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/admin.conf:5
```

How do I use the nginx in the container and access other container with setup config file?

Comment: There is some good background information on the `docs.docker.com` site.  [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) describes the process of building a custom image (you will lose work with this setup as soon as you delete the nginx container); [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes a straightforward way for two containers to communicate; or else [Use user-defined bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) if you really don't want to use Compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following commands (in the same order) to launch the containers:

```
sudo docker create -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=houzeyu2683@gmail.com -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=20121006 -p 5001:80 --name PSQLA dpage/pgadmin4
sudo docker create -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --link PSQLA:PSQLA --name Nginx nginx
sudo docker start PSQLA
sudo docker start Nginx
```

Now edit the Nginx configurations and you should not encounter the error anymore.

### Tl;dr

As mentioned in the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#communication-across-links):

> When you set up a link, you create a conduit between a source container and a recipient container. The recipient can then access select data about the source.

In order to access `PSQLA` from `Nginx` container, we need to link `Nginx` container to `PSQLA` container and not the other way around.

Now the question is: **What difference does that even makes?**

For this we need to understand how `--link` option works in docker.
The docker adds a host entry for the source container to the `/etc/hosts` file

We can verify this in the `/etc/hosts` file inside the Nginx container. It contains a new entry something like this (The id and IP might be different in your case):

`172.17.0.4   PSQLA 1117cf1e8a28`

This entry makes `Nginx` container access `PSQLA` container using the container name.

Please refer this for better understanding:

https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#updating-the-etchosts-file

### Important Note

As mentioned in the Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/):

> The --link flag is a legacy feature of Docker. It may eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate communication between two containers instead of using --link.